# Google Colab: redirect python output to a log file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a model using Tensorflow on Google CoLab.
Training process outputs a lot of lines to the screen.

Is there a way to redirect all python output to a log file and read it later?

P.S.
I tried this advice:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q2mhsj4bwwdQK-KZIxrIIKed8O11MQl0

But it works for system commands only (like "ls -la", etc.). With this code a python command is still writing to the standard output.

```
!python /root/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=/drive/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_300x300_coco14_sync.config \
    --model_dir=/drive/data/ \
    --num_train_steps=50000 \
    --num_eval_steps=2000 \
    --alsologtostderr
```

Answer (score 0):

Output can be captured to a file using standard linux redirection and utility "tee"

```
!python trainingScripty.py 2>&1 | tee TrainerLog.txt
```

Above command shall capture both output and error messages to TrainerLog.txt

Comment: When I try this command in colab:


 !python test.py 2>&1 | tee "/content/drive/Shared drives/result.txt'

I get the following error:


tee: '/content/drive/Shared drives/results.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Most probably its output path issue. Check if all subpaths exists and spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Amit's answer is good. As a side note: if you get an error message similar to:

```
tee: output.txt: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

and you have mounted a drive in your current colab notebook file using something like;

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
```

it may be helpful to recheck that you did not attempt to mount the gdrive drive again in the python script you are trying to run.